# Pythonic ways to create independent lists from a list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, python-3.4

(I searched on this website + internet, but couldn't find an answer)

I am starting from:

```
myList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

And I want to get something pythonic equivalent of

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
```

or

```
a, b, c = ([] for i in range(3))
```

That is I want to create as many lists as elements in the original list and use (assign?) the elements in the original list as names for the list created.

Do you have suggestions, please?

Comment: Don't do this. It almost *never* makes sense to introduce local names based upon other input. What are you *actually* trying to accomplish?

Comment: Kinda similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33888298/4099593). Do go through it.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but it does not sound right....Maybe try using a defaultdict. Have you looked into it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A dictionary sounds perfect for this situation

**Code:**

```
myList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dict_var=dict()
for key in myList:
    dict_var[key]=list()
print dict_var
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': [], 'c': [], 'b': []}
```

**Notes:**

- You can still do all the things you do with variable list like `append,extend etc.,.`

Comment: Wow, don't know `dict.fromkeys()` before. Looks like `collections.defaultdict()`.

Comment: @KevinGuan kind of it is just used to create list but you can still add a key of different value other than `list type` when you create from `fromkey`

Comment: @VigneshKalai `fromkeys` should not be used with mutable objects, unless it is absolutely necessary. It just uses the same object for all the keys, so all the values are one and same list.

Comment: @thefourtheye can you please elaborate I cannot understand what you are saying

Comment: @thefourtheye is correct. To see it do: `d = {}.fromkeys(['a', 'b'], [])` and then `d['a'].append(1)`.

Comment: @AskeDoerge yes agreed :)

Comment: @KevinGuan see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397153/append-value-to-one-list-in-dictionary-appends-value-to-all-lists-in-dictionary/23397182#23397182 you will get a little insight

Comment: It would be nice if the downvoter commented (which will not happen) why ?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of creating new variables, you can simply create a dictionary of lists, and then you can access the individual lists with the name, like this

```
>>> myList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> myDict = {item: [] for item in myList}
>>> myDict
{'c': [], 'a': [], 'b': []}
```

Now, you can use the lists, like this

```
>>> myDict['a'].append(1)
>>> myDict['b'].append(2)
>>> myDict['c'].append(3)
>>> myDict
{'c': [3], 'a': [1], 'b': [2]}
```

Answer (score 5):

Pythonic way is to use dictionary

```
myDict = {'a': [], 'b':[], 'c':[]}

myDict['a'].append("hello world")
print myDict['a'][0] # hello world
```

You can use list to create it

```
myList = ['a', 'b', 'c']

myDict = {}
for x in myList:
   myDict[x] = []
```

Answer (score 1):

What you asked can be achieved with:

```
myList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for item in myList:
    eval("{} = []".format(item))
```

but maybe you should use a dictionary of lists like the other guys mentioned.

See this too [How can you dynamically create variables via a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-a-while-loop)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your inputs. After some more search on the internet, I came out with:

```
myList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for item in myList:
 exec(item + ' = []')
```

Which gets exactly what I was after (and that can surely be written more compactedly).